# Convergence of a recurrent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Sorry if this was already proved (that sequence converges to $\pi$) but I cannot find that proof. So recurrent sequence is : 
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\sin(a_n)$$ 
and it seems if $0 < a_0 < 2\pi$ it converges to $\pi$.

If $\sin$ is replaced with $\cos$ it converges to – I think – $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in range $[0,3]$ at least

example Python program:

```
num=0.1
for i in range(10) :
    num+=math.sin(num)
```

result is : $3.141592653589793$

Again sorry if this is some well known fact - I'm not professional mathematician math is just hobby for me.

Comment: This sequence converges even very quickly to $\pi$ (the convergence rate is cubic, that means that the number of correct decimals from some point on increases by factor $3$ in each step).

Comment: With "cos" it should converge to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for start value in the range $[0,3]$ at least.

Comment: thx for answers yes you are right i will edit that for cos it converges to PI/2

Comment: Define $b_n : = a_n  - \pi$ and note that $$
\left| {b_{n + 1} } \right| = \left| {b_n  - \sin b_n } \right| < \frac{1}{6}\left| {b_n } \right|^3 .
$$

Comment: Note that this is the sequence produced by applying the Newton-Raphson method to find roots of $\cot{(x/2)}$ which has a single root $x=\pi$ for $x\in(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Yes Peter Foreman you are right - i thought i discovered something more interesting - this is just a case of Newton-Raphson method - thx for clarifying this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just focusing on $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sin{(a_n)}$ as @Grey suggested $b_n=a_n-\pi$
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\sin{(a_n)}\iff a_{n+1}-\pi=a_n-\pi-\sin{(a_n-\pi)}\iff \\
b_{n+1}=b_n-\sin{(b_n)}$$
and $b_0\in (-\pi,\pi)$.

Let's look at $f(x)=x-\sin{x}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and show a few properties. Obviously $b_{n+1}=f(b_n)$

---

**Proposition 1.** $f(x)$ is ascending.

Obviouly, since $f'(x)=1-\cos{x}\geq0$

---

**Proposition 2.** If $b_0\in[0,\pi]$ then $0\leq f(b_0)\leq b_0$.

Because $0\leq b_0-\sin(b_0)\leq b_0$, as $\sin{x}\geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$ [and](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/29/) $0\leq \sin{x}\leq x$.

---

**Proposition 3.** If $b_0\in[0,\pi]$ then $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is descending and bounded.

From **Proposition 1** and **2**

$$0\leq f(b_0)\leq b_0 \Rightarrow 0=f(0)\leq f(f(b_0))\leq f(b_0) \Rightarrow\\
0\leq b_2\leq b_1 \leq b_0$$ and by induction $0\leq b_{n+1}\leq b_{n}\leq b_0$

---

**Proposition 4.** If $b_0\in[-\pi,0)$ then $0\geq f(b_0)\geq b_0$.

Because $0\geq b_0-\sin(b_0)\geq b_0$, as $\sin{x}\leq0$ on $[-\pi,0)$ and $0\geq \sin{x}\geq x$.

---

**Proposition 5.** If $b_0\in[-\pi,0)$ then $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is ascending and bounded.

From **Proposition 1** and **4**

$$0\geq f(b_0)\geq b_0 \Rightarrow 0=f(0)\geq f(f(b_0))\geq f(b_0) \Rightarrow\\
0\geq b_2\geq b_1 \geq b_0$$ and by induction $0\geq b_{n+1}\geq b_{n}\geq b_0$

---

Finally, in both cases we have a monotonic and [bounded sequence, thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) **the limit** of $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **exists**. Of course for $b_0=\pi$ or $b_0=-\pi$ we obtain constant sequences.

This also means that **the limit** of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **exists** and you can find it from $L=L+\sin{L}$.